# Solve $(\frac{x}{y} + 1 )dx + (\frac{x}{y} -1 )dy = 0$. Is my solution correct?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I tried to solve:

$$(\frac{x}{y} + 1 )dx + (\frac{x}{y} -1 )dy = 0$$

$(y+1)dx+(x+1)dy=0$

$M(x, y) = \frac{x}{y} + 1$

$N(x, y) = \frac{x}{y} -1$

Then, we can multiply both $M$ and $N$ by $y$ to get:

$yM(x, y) = M^{*}(x, y) = x + y$

$yN(x, y) = N^{*}(x, y) = x -y$

$\frac {\partial M^{*}}{\partial y}=1=\frac {\partial N^{*}}{\partial x}$

Hence, the differential equation is exact.

We take: $\phi_x = x+y$

We integrate with resect to $x$ and get: $\frac{x^2}{2} +xy + h(y)$

Then we differentiate with respect to $y$ and get: $\phi_y = x + h'(y)$ which is equal to $x-y$

Hence: $x + h'(y) = x-y \implies h'(y) = -y$

Integrating both sides with respect to $y$: $h(y) = -\frac{y^2}{2}$.

Our solution:

$\frac{x^2}{2} +xy -\frac{y^2}{2} = C$

Is that correct?

Comment: The solution is correct

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you! I've got one more and I don't know how to start. $x' = 2x \cdot cos^2 (t) + sin (t)$. Could you give me some hint? Anything to google information on that type of equations.

Comment: Let $u=\frac{x}{y}$ ...